# Cannot destructure property '' of 'req.params' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, request

okay so i'm trying to make a put request here is the code:

```
// Route : Take Cart by an admin
router.put('/take-cart/:cartId', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const cartId = parseInt(req.params.cartId, 10);
    const { token } = req.headers;

    const isAdminAuthenticated = await authenticateAdminWithToken(token);

    if (!isAdminAuthenticated) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
    }

    const { adminId } = isAdminAuthenticated.dataValues.id;

    console.log(cartId, adminId);
    await cartController.takeCart(cartId, adminId);

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Cart taken successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to take the cart' });
  }
});
```

here is the output
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "nom", "prenom", "email",
"numeroTelephone", "username", "password", "isAdmin", "createdAt",
"updatedAt" FROM "Admins" AS "Admin" WHERE "Admin"."id" = 1;
1
3 undefined
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'cartId' of 'req.params' as it is
undefined.
at Object.takeCart

I was trying to make a request and expected the to pass the cartId as a number instead of a string but for some reasons I keep getting an undefined property even after cinverting from a string to an integer

Comment: log the req object before 'try' block. Sometimes it can be req.data.params

Comment: try this req?.params?.cartId to all values